# Pandas: replace all value in column with frequent value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example DataFrame

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({
                        "DAY":[25, 25, 27, 28],
                        "TRNDESCR":['Transfer','Transfer','Transfer','Transfer'],
                        "TRNAMT":[-10,-10,-10,-5]
                        })
    df
```

Output df:

```
DAY TRNDESCR    TRNAMT
0   25  Transfer    -10
1   25  Transfer    -10
2   27  Transfer    -10
3   28  Transfer    -5
```

So, i want to replace all value inside TRNAMT column with frequent value. 
My expected result is:

```
    DAY TRNDESCR    TRNAMT
0   25  Transfer    -10
1   25  Transfer    -10
2   27  Transfer    -10
3   28  Transfer    -10
```

Can someone help me. Thank you so much

Comment: `df['TRNAMT'] = df['TRNAMT'].mode()[0]` ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) with select first value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df['TRNAMT'] = df['TRNAMT'].mode().iat[0]
print (df)
   DAY  TRNDESCR  TRNAMT
0   25  Transfer     -10
1   25  Transfer     -10
2   27  Transfer     -10
3   28  Transfer     -10
```

Alternative solution with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and first index value:

```
df['TRNAMT'] = df['TRNAMT'].value_counts().index[0]
```